# Awk trying to return value of users logged in for more than 4 minutes

Tags: awk

I am using a  file in which the time a user spends logged in,  is in the $10 field.  I am trying to list all users that are not currently logged in and that have been logged on for more than 4 minutes
I have tried this:

```
last | awk '($10!"in"){if $10>00.04)print $10,$1}' sort -nr | less
```

It returned no information, if I eliminate the  ($10!"in") it returns people that are "logged in". Is this a syntax problem or are hours, min not comparable with a greater than sign?

Comment: in your own words ,what are you trying to do with `($10!"in")`?

Comment: I am trying to eliminate the lines that have the text " in " appear in the feild, that way i can compare just the values greater than 4 minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `$10!"in"` doesn't work is because the operator you're looking for is `!=` (not equal to). That alone is not enough yet, though; `$10 > 00.04` is not going to work when `$10` has a value like `(12:34)`; you'll have to split it. A possibility is

```
last | awk '$10 != "in" { gsub(/\(\)/, "", $10); split($10, t, ":"); if(t[1] > 0 || t[2] > 4) print $10, $1 }' | sort -nr  | less
```

The awk code is

```
$10 != "in" {                 # in a line where $10 is not "in"
  gsub(/\(\)/, "", $10)       # remove parentheses from $10
  split($10, t, ":")          # split $10 at the : into t
  if(t[1] > 0 || t[2] > 4) {  # t[1] is the hours, t[2] the minutes, so this
                              # checks whether $10 is more than 4 minutes
    print $10, $1             # and prints $10, $1 ($10 without parentheses
                              # because we removed them). If that is not
                              # desired, make a copy of $10 before paren
                              # removal and splitting.
  }
}
```

I have not checked whether the output of `last` is standardized, by the way. I suspect it is not, and so that this is unlikely to be very portable.

Answer (score 1):

```
last |awk '{if($10>00.04 && $10 !~ "in" ){print $10,$1}}'|sort -nr | less
```

..

```
$10>00.04 && $10 !~ "in" # if field 10 is greater than 00.04 and does not matches "in"
```

Comment: awk has a tendency to search a field for number matches, even if that field contains mixes of number and alphas.